# Log Azure Data Factory Pipeline run events to Azure App Insights

Tags: azure-data-factory

Is there a way to publish ADF pipeline run events with status to App Insights?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Per my knowledge, you could use Web Activity in the ADF to invoke the Application Insights REST API after execution of your main activities(Or using Execute Pipeline Activity to execute your root pipeline and get the status or output of it).Then send it to App Insights REST API.

More details,please refer to this document:https://www.ben-morris.com/using-azure-data-factory-with-the-application-insights-rest-api/