# How to store Azure DataFactory logs to ApplicationInsights

Tags: logging, azure-data-factory, azure-application-insights

When running Azure Data Factory pipeline, We want to do audit logging in Azure Application Insights.
Can anyone help with any step by step guide on how to log data into Application Insights from Azure DataFactory pipeline tasks?

Thanks

Comment: Hello, if the answer is helpful, please accept it as answer. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Currently, ADF is not directly hooked up with Application Insights. But as per [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61393250/10185816), you can try to use Web Activity in the ADF to invoke the Application Insights REST API after execution of your main activities.

And for ADF, we do suggest using [Azure Monitor](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/monitor-using-azure-monitor#configure-diagnostic-settings-and-workspace) instead of Application Insights.